# Neo4j CSV Load: How to avoid Null and escape characters

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to load large volume of data into graph using CSV Load script (xyx.cpl) and Neo4jShell.

Mostly it is doing well. Sometimes I am receiving following errors

1. Cannot merge node using null property value ...
2. Error related to escape characters

So, seeking assistance to understand the best way to handle this issues in import script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IS it possible to avoid null issue using MERGE () ....
 ON CREATE SET  statement

Comment: Can you show your Cypher code?

Answer (score 2):

**Cannot merge node using null property value**

You can use a `WITH` statement to filter out rows that have a null value for the property you are using in the `MERGE`. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row 
WITH row WHERE row.name IS NOT NULL
MERGE (p:Person {name: row.name})
SET p.age = row.age
...
```

**Error related to escape characters**

Can you be a bit more specific about the error you are getting / show a Cypher and data example?

Without seeing your specific error / code here is some info that might help:

- the character for string quotation within your CSV file is a double quote `"`
- the escape character is `\`
- more info and some examples [here](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) and [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html#load-csv-import-data-containing-escaped-characters)